# Angular Change Detection Issue: View Updates Only on First Button Click (Using NgZone Noop)

Tags: angular

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with change detection in my Angular application. When I click the button to trigger the addNewTask method, the view updates correctly for the first time, clearing the input field (newTask). However, subsequent clicks do not result in further updates to the view.

Component Code:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  newTask: string = '';

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  addNewTask(): void {
    this.newTask = '';
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
   
  }
}
```

Template Code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="New task" [(ngModel)]="newTask" class="input-group-field" />

<!-- Button to trigger addNewTask method -->
<button class="button" (click)="addNewTask()">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  <span class="icon-text-margin"> Add </span>
</button>
```

I'm using NgZone with the noop strategy.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule, { ngZone: 'noop' })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I would appreciate any insights into why the view updates only on the first click, especially when using NgZone with the noop strategy. Are there potential reasons or common pitfalls I might be overlooking?

Comment: Check your browser console for errors

Comment: There is no error in my console  ....

Comment: I was thinking if 2-way data binding have some issues with noop CD... In my experience calling detectChanges should have been enough...